# How to reroute traffic coming from a subdomain to a specific port on the server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns, port

I have an AWS EC2 instance running 2 webapplications with pm2. The server's address is configured as `test.example.com`. (GoDaddy DNS A-record pointing to EC2's elastic IP) Application 1 runs on port 3000 and Application 2 runs on port 4000.

What I want to achieve is:

1. All traffic coming from `subdomain1`, goes to the application running on port 3000.
2. All traffic coming from `subdomain2`, goes to port 4000.

Now here comes the tricky part, the endresult should look like this `test.sub1.example.com` and `test.sub2.example.com`. (I'm a noob at *subdomaining*, so it might have to be configured as `sub1.test.example.com` and `sub2.test.example.com` I don't know)

I've tried doing this with setting `SRV` records on GoDaddy pointing to a specific port, but it just doesn't work.

```
Service  : _something
Protocol : _http
Name     : sub2
Target   : test.example.com
Priotiry : 0
Weight   : 0
Port     : 4000
TTL      : 1 hour
```

I've also read this [reddit article](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/7gs0hx/question_domain_not_pointing_to_correct_port/), but as far as I know it will redirect all traffic towards the server to 1 specific port. Which wouldn't be a problem, if I had 2 different EC2 instances each running their own webapplication and configured it that way, but that's not an option.

Extra info: EC2 instance runs `Ubuntu 16.04`, webserver on EC2 is `nginx 1.14.0`

Comment: `SRV` records do work and are used by various applications with notable exception: web browsers do **NOT** use them at all. So you can publish SRV records but browsers will not see them at all, and either go straight to 80/443 by default or go the port written in the URL, such as `http://www.example.com:4321/`. To do otherwise, you need to setup a reverse proxy that will get queries on 80/443 and redirects or proxies them to the various relevant port based on the hostname or URL path of incoming query. This is also not very related to programming, so slightly offtopic here.

Comment: Can you give me a lead on where to start looking on how to setup this reverse proxy stuff? Also (more meta) which stackexchange should I post this on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have found a simple solution:

I've added 3 subdomains on GoDaddy's DNS:

```
A: test.example.com            -> <aws-elastic-IP>
A: subdomain1.test.example.com -> <aws-elastic-IP>
A: subdomain2.test.example.com -> <aws-elastic-IP>
```

then in nginx's default config, for each subdomain added a proxy pass that points at the right port

```
server { # landing page
    server_name  test.example.com;
    index index.html;
    root   /home/user/project-source;
    location / {
        root   /home/user/project-source;
    }
    ...
}

server { # webapp running on port 3000
    server_name subdomain1.test.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        ...
    }
    ...
}

server { # webapp running on post 4000
    server_name subsomain2.test.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```